# Flowplayer does not play http live streaming

Tags: internet-explorer, video, http-live-streaming, flowplayer, mjpeg

The aim was to reproduce mjpeg stream from an IP camera (Cisco PVC2300) in my web site, but with IE. I read that this is not possible (no problems with Chrome and Firefox), so here it started the adventure. I tried with multiple scripts/applets in IE (Quicktime, Cambozola.jar, Paparazzo.js...) in order to try to reproduce MJPEG stream in any player. The result was unsatisfactory.

Then, I thought of using a player that was able to reproduce HTTP live streaming (JWplayer, FlowPlayer). Still not working.

The thing is that I can view the stream with VLC, opening the network location of the camera (http://user:password@ip_address/img/video.mjpeg). Also in Chrome and Firefox. But I need to use IE.

I tried to catch the stream in my server with VLC and resending over the network:

```
vlc -vvv http://user:password@ip_address/img/video.mjpeg --sout '#standard{access=http, mux=mp4, dst=:8083/video.mjpeg}'
```

Again, with VLC in the client side, I can reproduce the new stream (http://myserver.com:8083/video.mjpeg), but cannot embed the video in HTML. I tried with `<video>` tag from HTML5. Nothing happens.

The last test I did was to try Flowplayer with HttpStreaming:

```
<div id="videoStream"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $f(id, "http://myserver.com/media/flash/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",
     {
        clip: {
                url: 'http://myserver.com:8083/video.mjpeg',
                provider: 'httpstreaming',
                autoPlay: false,
                urlResolvers: 'httpstreaming'
             },
        plugins: {
            httpstreaming: {
                    url: 'http://myserver.com/media/flash/flowplayer.httpstreaming-3.2.11.swf'
            },
            controls: null
        }
     }
</script>
```

Obviously, nothing is shown in Flowplayer.

Please, if anybody has any idea of how I can reproduce Live Http Streaming in IE or if I have some error in my code, it would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!